# R Using function to clean individual files and then aggregate into one master file

Tags: r, function, datetime, directory, lapply

I would like to apply the following function across every file within a given directory. Then, I want to combine the processed data from each individual file into one master file that is ordered by date-time. The function below works well for cleaning each individual file separately, but I would like clean and merge everything all at once.

```
clean.data <- function(fpath){
    require(magrittr)
    require(dplyr)
    df <- read.csv(fpath, skip = 30, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ## the raw data has an unecessary 30 line header
    colnames(df) <- c("date","time","value")
    df$datetime <-strptime(paste(df$date, df$time), "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
    df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime, format = dt_format, tz = "UTC")
    df <- df[,-c(1:2)] ## remove redundant columns
    df <- df[,c(2:1)] ## reorder so date-time is the first column
    df %>% 
        group_by(datetime = cut(datetime, breaks = "1 min")) %>%
        summarize(value = mean(value))
}
```

Here is an example of the [raw data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By6o_bZ8CGwub1Y0TzVlWDFaM1U).

This is the format that I want my data to be in after cleaning and merging all the files within a directory:

```
             datetime     value
1 2017-03-02 16:25:00      1610
2 2017-03-02 16:26:00       862
3 2017-03-02 16:27:00       639
4 2017-03-02 16:28:00       563
5 2017-03-02 16:29:00       554
6 2017-03-02 16:30:00       558
```

I'm thinking that this should work, but I haven't had much luck yet:

```
read.files <- function(fpaths, FUN, ...){
    tbls <- lapply(fpaths, FUN, ...)
    dta <- do.call(rbind, tbls)
    return(dta)
}

read.files(fpaths, clean.data())
```

Comments and questions appreciated, thanks!

**Solution:**

```
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.txt$", all.files = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)

library(plyr)
library(magrittr)
import.list <- ldply(filenames, clean.data) %>% plyr::arrange(import.list$datetime) ## make sure to specify using plyr instead of dplyr!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: start with a list of all the files, then use ldply to apply your function across all files, and order the resulting data frame:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "\\.txt$", all.files = FALSE, full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE, ignore.case = FALSE) #creates list of names of all .txt files in folder 
#adjust this as appropriate for your files...

library(plyr)
import.list <- ldply (filenames, clean.data)[order(datetime),] 
#I think you can do this in one line, but if a problem, can always create data frame with ldply first, then order...
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The `list.files()` function was working properly once I changed `full.names = TRUE`. The `ldply (filenames, clean.data)` was also working properly, but the `[order(datetime),]` would output a dataframe with only the first row. Instead, I used `%>% plyr::arrange(import.list$datetime)` and everything worked! Note, you have to specify the `plyr::arange()` instead of `dplyr::arrange()`, because for some reason, only `plyr` can order POSIXct format datetimes.